# Relocating georeferenced image, shapefiles and grid using Spatial Adjustment tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, georeferencing, rubbersheeting

I somehow georeferenced an image about 120 miles east of where I should have georeferenced it. This should be a simple fix, except that I then proceeded to digitize that extremely detailed image (read: time consuming) into two shapefiles and also gridded that data all based on the incorrect location.

A friend recommended to just re-georeference the original image and use the [Spatial Adjustment tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment.htm) to simply move the shapefiles and grid over to the right location.

The problem is: I've never used the Spatial Adjustment tool and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this properly. There are three options: edge snap, rubbersheet and transform.

Can anyone help or suggest an easier way to achieve this without having to re-digitize everything?

Answer (score 7):

If your data doesn't have to be too accurate, you could try moving the shapefile features by dragging it to its proper location.

> 1. Click the Edit tool . [image]
> 2. Click the feature or features you want to move. Hold down the Shift key while clicking features to select additional features.
> 3. Click and drag the feature or features to the desired location.

As for the Spatial Adjustment Tool, I think it's the Transformation Tool you want. According to the docs:

> Transformations move or shift data within a coordinate system. They
> are often used to convert data from unknown digitizer or scanner units
> to real-world coordinates. Transformations can also be used to convert
> units within a coordinate system, such as converting feet to meters.
> To convert data between coordinate systems, such as geographic to UTM,
> you should project the data instead.

Under the Transformation Tools, I think you need the Affine transformation

[image]

More specifically, the translation option as the feature are just shifted to the east of their proper positions.

Here is the workflow from the [ArcGIS docs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_spatial_adjustment/001t000000t5000000/)

> While each of the spatial adjustment functions is used for a different
> purpose, the steps for setting up and performing an adjustment are
> essentially the same:
>
> 1. Start ArcMap.
> 2. Create a new map or open an existing one.
> 3. Add the data you want to edit to your map.
> 4. Add the Editor toolbar to ArcMap.
> 5. Add the Spatial Adjustment toolbar to ArcMap.
> 6. Start your edit session.
> 7. Choose the input data for the adjustment.
> 8. Choose a spatial adjustment method.
> 9. Create displacement links.
> 10. Perform the adjustment.
> 11. Stop your edit session and save your edits.
>
> There is no need to save the map—all edits made to the database will
> automatically be reflected the next time you open the map.